# SQL ranking/sorting the most recent record by year for the same person

Tags: sql, sql-server

What i am trying to do is only get the most recent record of each year,

```
SELECT pid, obsdate, obsvalue
FROM CPSFactDimension.Fact.LiverFunction
WHERE HDID = 40
    AND obsdate >= '2006/01/01'
    AND obsdate < '2017/12/31'
```

some outcome looks like this, but what is a good idea to ONLY filter the most recent record of each year for the same person?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MUDk.png]

looking for something like this

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1eOT.png]

Comment: This has been asked and answered dozens and dozens of times. You use ROW_NUMBER with a partition by.

Comment: Use this question, and change the answer to go by year instead of by month:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436868/get-last-record-from-each-month

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Last Record From Each Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436868/get-last-record-from-each-month)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` function :

```
select t.*
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by pid, year(obsdate) order by obsdate desc) seq 
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```